# Run CDK inside lambda execution

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have to update CloudWatch Dashboards often.

I'm trying to run CDK from a lambda execution to get the Cloudformation template.

When it is executing the constructor `app = cdk.App(outdir="./tmp")` it throws an exception

```
[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
  File "/var/task/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 1440, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "/var/task/aws_cdk/_jsii/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import aws_cdk.asset_awscli_v1._jsii
  File "/var/task/aws_cdk/asset_awscli_v1/_jsii/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __jsii_assembly__ = jsii.JSIIAssembly.load(
  File "/var/task/jsii/_runtime.py", line 55, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    self.provider.load(LoadRequest(name=name, version=version, tarball=tarball))
  File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 352, in load
    return self._process.send(request, LoadResponse)
  File "/var/task/jsii/_utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
    stored.append(fgetter(self))
  File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 347, in _process
    process.start()
  File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 260, in start
    self._process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)Exception ignored in: <function _NodeProcess.__del__ at 0x7f80ae481e50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 228, in __del__
self.stop()
File "/var/task/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 291, in stop
assert self._process.stdin is not None
AttributeError: '_NodeProcess' object has no attribute '_process'
```

Is there a way to run CDK from a lambda execution?

Comment: It looks like you need the node executable available in lambda environment

Comment: why don't you run it as part of a cicd pipeline? this seems very complicated to be honest...

Comment: I can't run with CICD pipeline because It needs to be updated when an ASG lifecycle event happens. I was able to do it adding the CDK and nodejs inside a lambda image After I created a lambda using the image. I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that using lambda with a docker image.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -


RUN yum install -y nodejs

RUN npm install -g aws-cdk

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

And here is the lambda code sample

```
import json
import aws_cdk as cdk
import boto3

from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_sqs as sqs,
)
from constructs import Construct

class MonitorPocPythonStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, queue_name: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # The code that defines your stack goes here

        # example resource
        queue = sqs.Queue(
            self, queue_name,
            visibility_timeout=Duration.seconds(300),
        )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("new 3")
    cloudformation = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    app = cdk.App(outdir="/tmp")
    MonitorPocPythonStack(app, "MonitorPocPythonStack", event['queue'])
    app.synth()
    
    with open("/tmp/MonitorPocPythonStack.template.json", "r") as file:
        template_body = file.read()
    
    cloudformation.update_stack(
        StackName="MonitorPocPythonStack",
        TemplateBody=template_body,
        Capabilities=[
            'CAPABILITY_IAM','CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND'
        ],
    )
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "hello world",
            # "location": ip.text.replace("\n", "")
        }),
    }
```